# ScalaTest with Scalajs: No tests get executed

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala.js

My test suits execute fine with jvm, but if I enable scalajs plugin in sbt and run `sbt test` I get the following output:

```
[info] Tests:
[info] - should finishTest1
[info] - should finishTest2
...
[info] - should finishTest100
[info] Run completed in 4 seconds, 580 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 0, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] No tests were executed.
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Oct 29, 2019 1:27:24 PM
```

So it seems that the test might get executed, but the their results get ignored? I am not really sure where should I start in order to fix such problem.

The test file looks like this:

```scala
import org.scalatest._

class Tests extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  it should "finishTest1" in {
    assert(... == ...)
  }
  ...
}
```

Furthemore, although `sbt test` returns the above output, running the tests trough intellij results in `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/scalatest/tools/Runner`!

Comment: How do you depend on ScalaTest in your build? The typical cause for that symptom is that you depend on it `%%` instead of `%%%`.

Comment: I use `%%%` in my build.